# Is it unsafe to pass an unsigned long to a function which uses a long?

Tags: c, prototype, unsigned

**Foreword**: I am not allowed to use any functions from the C library

I have this function:

```
char *to_base(long nbr, char *base)
{
    static char buffer[50];
    char    *ptr;
    int     base_len;

    ptr = &buffer[49];
    *ptr = 0;
    base_len = ft_strlen(base);
    while (nbr != 0)
    {
        *--ptr = base[nbr % base_len];
        nbr /= base_len;
    }
    return (ptr);
}
```

As we can see it takes a long. In my program I have an *unsigned long* which I have to translate into its hexadecimal value. Is it unsafe to pass the *unsigned long* at this function ? If yes how can I make it work ?

EDIT :
Here is how I am currently using it:

```
unsigned long    val;
char            *hexa;

val = (unsigned long)va_arg(*list, void *);
hexa = to_base(val, "0123456789abcdef");
```

Comment: The problem is that your **function** is not safe to use with **signed long** :D

Comment: Just use `sprintf()`.  That's at least multithread-safe, something the function you posted is **not**.  Heck, the one you posted isn't safe in that a subsequent use will wipe out the value from a previous use.

Comment: This question boils down to "is it safe to convert unsigned integer to signed" (if we ignore unrelated issues). The answer can be found in C standard http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3 (*Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.*)

Comment: For what it's worth, this function is just chock full of "What?? No!" moments. If the objective is to convert a number to a string, use an existing library function. This problem has been solved decades ago and is in the standard library.

Comment: Read up on [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) because this code is the sort of thing that calls for Real Talk and an intervention. `%xl` does what you want and then some.

Comment: I have a project which makes me recode the printf method. I am not allowd to use the standard C library. I must code everything myself.

Comment: `If yes how can I make it work ?` Write separate function for `unsigned long`. `val = (unsigned long)va_arg(*list, void *);` I do not believe that's valid code or that it does what you think it does. Your function will break hard with negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it unsafe to pass the unsigned long at this function ?

It's "safe", as in the program will not format your hard drive or start another world war.

Passed function arguments are *converted* to the argument type. The unsigned value will be *converted* to a signed one. All architectures today use twos-complement, it's easy to predict the result. Your compiler should document the behavior, ex. in [gcc implementation defined beahvior](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation):

> The result of, or the signal raised by, converting an integer to a signed integer type when the value cannot be represented in an object of that type (C90 6.2.1.2, C99 and C11 6.3.1.3).

> For conversion to a type of width N, the value is reduced modulo 2^N to be within range of the type; no signal is raised.

"reduced modulo 2^N" - basically 2^N is subtracted until the value is within range. So if you have 32-bit `long`s and have `(long)(unsigned long)4294967196ul` so you subtract 2^32 from the value and it's equal to `(long)-100`.

> If yes how can I make it work ?

Properly handle negative numbers.

And write a separate function for unsigned and signed numbers.

Also `(unsigned long)va_arg(*list, void *);` is casting a `void*` pointer value to an `unsigned long` (?). Most probably you want `va_arg(list, unsigned long)` - to take `unsigned long` from arguments.

Comment: I'm recoding the printf func and I'm at the %p format. This is why I use va_arg(list, void*) to get the pointer address. I've been told to then cast it as an unsigned long.